# import csv into SAS;WARNING: A character that could not be transcoded has been replaced in record XXX

Tags: csv, sas

When I import a large csv into SAS, it always shows that ‘WARNING: A Character that could not be transcoded has been replaced in record XXXXX’. What should I do for it?

Thanks in advance.

```
1 /**********************************************************************
2 * PRODUCT: SAS
3 * VERSION: 9.4
4 * CREATOR: External File Interface
5 * DATE: 06MAR18
6 * DESC: Generated SAS Datastep Code
7 * TEMPLATE SOURCE: (None Specified.)
8 ***********************************************************************/
9 data WORK.Companies ;
10 %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
11 infile 'E:\PATSTAT\Companies.csv' delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=13106 firstobs=2 ;
12 informat person_id best32. ;
13 informat person_name $46. ;
...
36 informat nuts3 $5. ;
37 informat nuts3_name $30. ;
38 format person_id best12. ;
39 format person_name $46. ;
...
62 format nuts3 $5. ;
63 format nuts3_name $30. ;
64 input
...
89 nuts3 $
90 nuts3_name $
91 ;
92 if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1); /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
93 run;
NOTE: A byte-order mark in the file "E:\PATSTAT\Companies.csv" (for fileref "#LN00025") indicates that the data is encoded in "utf-8". This encoding will be used to process the file.
NOTE: The infile 'E:\PATSTAT\Companies.csv' is: Filename=E:\PATSTAT\Companies.csv, RECFM=V, LRECL=52424, File Size (bytes)=228293377, Last Modified=03 March 2018 19:12:47 o'clock, Create Time=27 November 2017 14:10:57 o'clock
WARNING: A character that could not be transcoded has been replaced in record 775.
WARNING: A character that could not be transcoded has been replaced in record 857.
...
WARNING: A character that could not be transcoded has been replaced in record 10881.
NOTE: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached. Further warnings of this type will not be printed.
NOTE: 1048575 records were read from the infile 'E:\PATSTAT\Companies.csv'.
The minimum record length was 103.
The maximum record length was 680.
NOTE: The data set WORK.COMPANIES has 1048575 observations and 26 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time): real time 7.28 seconds cpu time 3.19 seconds
1048575 rows created in WORK.Companies from E:\PATSTAT\Companies.csv.
NOTE: WORK.COMPANIES data set was successfully created.
NOTE: The data set WORK.COMPANIES has 1048575 observations and 26 variables.
```

Comment: Make sure you are running SAS using Unicode support. What setting do you have for the system option ENCODING?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly please? I just started to use SAS. Thanks in advance.@Tom

Comment: How are you running SAS? If you want to be able to handle multi-byte characters then you need to start SAS with the proper settings. Otherwise it will try to map the characters to the single byte encoding that your session is using, usually WLATIN1. You can use this program to see the settings.  `proc options option=encoding; run;`

Comment: thanks a lot, Tom. you are right. it shows 
      1 proc options option=encoding;
      2 run;
      SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4 TS1M3
      ENCODING=WLATIN1 Specifies the default character-set encoding for the SAS session.
but what should I do next? I want to import a csv which includes characters, date and number into SAS.
Besides, could you recommend some introductory books about SAS please? @Tom

Comment: How are you starting SAS? What operating system are you using? What operating system is SAS running on if it is running on a different machine?

Comment: My operating system is X64_7pro win 6.1.7601. is that ok?@Tom

Comment: So when my IT support team installed SAS on my PC they setup multiple icons to start SAS.  One is labeled "SAS 9.4 (English)" and one is labeled "SAS 9.4 (Unicode support)".  So if I start with the latter then encoding is set to utf-8 and these type of transcoding issues disappear.

Comment: Thank you very much,Tom. The transcoding issues disappear following your method. @Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start SAS with unicode support to read UTF-8 characters.

You could try setting `ENCODING=ANY` on the `INFILE` or `FILENAME` statement in your current SAS session.  The encoding shouldn't matter for the numbers. But if you really have UTF-8 characters that cannot be transcoded into single byte WLATIN1 characters then you will probably have trouble working with those strings.